# Azure: How to change location of App service and App Service plan on BizSpark subscription

Tags: azure, azure-app-service-plans

My startup company got an Azure BizSpark subscription. I have just created an API App and App service plan. Our company is located in Northern Europe but the location of both the API service and the App service plan is "South Central US". I did not see any options to specify the location when I created the API app. I also don't see any options to change the location now that the app is created. Is this a limitation of the BizSpark subscription or can I somehow change the location?

Comment: Have a look at this: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/blog/azure-data-center-migration-just-got-easier/

Comment: I'm afraid to say I have this problem, with the wrong region and also on BizSpark but I don't remember setting up the region.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You cannot change the location of an app service plan, regardless of subscription type. You simply need to create a new app service plan in the region you want, and then redeploy your code.

Comment: Maybe related UserVoice: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps/suggestions/20090146-can-switch-region-in-anytime

Comment: Not ideal solution but I guess that is why Microsoft give you free credit to find these things out before you start on real developments.

Comment: azure web app has "clone app" feature it will let you clone app into different region also

Comment: Still not possible afaik

Answer (score 34):

Whilst you can't move the server you can backup of a server then create a new one using the backup as the base.

This is often easier than starting from scratch.

Comment: Why was this downvoted. It is literally the only solution other than starting a new server from scratch.

Comment: What is 'the server' referencing in relation to App Service & App Service Plan?

Comment: 'the server' refers to the app service itself.

Answer (score 0):

In the same direction as @David Makogon and @Arjun Vachhani stated:

> The region in which your app runs is the region of the App Service plan it's in. However, you cannot change an App Service plan's region. If you want to run your app in a different region, one alternative is app cloning. Cloning makes a copy of your app in a new or existing App Service plan in any region.

Source: [Move an app to a different region from Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-plan-manage#move-an-app-to-a-different-region)